# session not getting on firefox when page is loaded first time

Tags: php, session, firefox, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm using a session variable to hold the value of a variable called 'myage' as seen below

```
if(transfer) {
        $.ajax(
        {
          url: '../php/setSession.php',
          data: {
            'link': link,
            'myage': myage
          },
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(output)
          {
            console.log("session variables set");
          }
        }
        );

        window.location.href = "../transfer/school.html";
      }
    });
```

And my setSession.php looks as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myage'] = $_POST['myage'];
?>
```

However, the trouble is that, the very first time in a session, when I log in to the site, the session variables are not getting set, and consequently, 'myage' shows empty value in a text box where I'm printing out it's value. Next time onwards, it works fine.

How can I correct this behavior?

EDIT : This problem is only on firefox, on other browsers, the SESSION variable gets set from the first use in the session onwards.

Comment: the first code is related to login functionality? if yes show full code?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh , it's not related to login, but the value of myage comes from a server, and that is getting populated correctly even the first time. But when I write it to a session variable in setSession.php and then read from it, I read NULL instead of the actual value first time.

Is there any other information I can provide, sorry my very first time with web development.

Comment: In your first page write session_start() also.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh , I tried my original code once again and turns out that only on firefox, the session variable $_SESSION['myage'] is not getting saved the first time when I use the site. On chrome, the same works. Can you suggest me how I can get around this. Just to reiterate, the first code is a javascript function which sends the value of 'myage' as a post(this value is correct and non-zero/not null) to setSession.php. But once it gets there, the session variable does not get populated with the value(the first time during this session when I use the site).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to redirect on success.

```
if(transfer) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/setSession.php',
      data: {
        'link': link,
        'myage': myage
      },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(output) {
        console.log("session variables set");
        window.location.href = "../transfer/school.html"; // <-- this line
      }
    });
}
```